# XMLHttpRequest cannot load - file footer.html, "Error: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest'

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-plugins

I have two of the same site. My 1st site is http://educationaboveall.org/ and the 2nd is http://www.savantgenius.com .

1st site is loading properly on every device without any error but the 2nd (www.savantgenius.com) site is not loading properly in mobile and table devices. It is only loading properly in desktop browser. I have also found 32 console error.

Are there any **jQuery** issues? And please tell me how to be able to fix it.

> I'm getting the "XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   file:///D:/Work%20File/My%20Work%20File/mY%20Work%20Backup/Sophie/Work%20File/footer.html.
>   Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP." and "Error: Failed
>   to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load
>   'file:///D:/Work%20File/My%20Work%20File/mY%20Work%20Backup/Sophie/Work%20File/footer.html"
>   error, but I don't know what's causing it nor how to fix it.

Please see the screenshot - http://prntscr.com/4fm0d8

Answer (score 2):

I Think that you should call it from a http webserver and not like simple file in browser. This mean request a file in a web server like `http://localhost/XML/catalog.html` not from `file:///E:/Projects/XML/catalog.html`.

Answer (score 1):

It is as the message says:

```
cannot load file:///D:/Work%20File/My%20Work%20File/mY%20Work%20Backup/Sophie/Work%20File/footer.html. .
```

You are referencing to a file on a Windows boxes filesystem and not in a webservers folder.

Second: you have a `CORS`-issue (which in this case is caused by the filesystem reference)

```
Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP
```

See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) for more infos.
To solve the issue, you have to configure your webserver to allow such requests. Check your webservers manual.

Comment: I can't understand what I will do now. :(

Comment: What server are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with my InfluxDB connection and it turns out I did not prepend the URL settings in the datasource with 'http://'. This could be nicer in Grafana, e.g. mentioning there is no protocol defined for accessing the source.

In your case it's clear that you somehow configured Grafana to look for D:\, which is not accessible for your browser. So check your data source URL.