# Retrieve an XML file (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, html, xml

I found this code on W3Schools and improve it , in the end it became sth like this :

```
    function LoadXML(){
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  try{
xmlhttp.open("GET","file.xml",false);
    alert("first place");

xmlhttp.send();
    alert("2nd place");
}
catch(err){
alert(err.message);
}
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML; 

document.write("<table><tr><th>Artist</th><th>Title</th></tr>");
var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("CD");
for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
  { 
  document.write("<tr><td>");
 alert( document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("ARTIST")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue));
  document.write("</td><td>");
 alert( document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("TITLE")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue));
  document.write("</td></tr>");
  }
document.write("</table>");
}
```

This code is available in :[W3School Code](http://www.w3schools.com/dom/dom_nodes_access.asp)

But when I want to run this code in my own PC , an error occur in try and catch block ! 
It shows that "Cannot load the "file.xml" .
When I search for this error a topic in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25461367/xmlhttprequest-cannot-load-file-footer-html-error-failed-to-execute-send) is the reason of error , So It seems that I can't do something like that in my Own PC cuz it uses http and need a server or a local host .

But This code is for a project in my class and one of the scenarios is (Retrieve Element of An XML File and show its content on my HTML page) !

I am sure that they will test this program on their own PCs .

So can anyone explain me a way to accomplish this scenario in A PC ?!

Note : The target browser is IE 8.0

Thanks in advance

Comment: If `file.xml` does not exist in the same directory that the html file you are working from in your local machine exists, there will be no file to load.  Target browser is IE 8?  Wow  Your class should not be using W3Schools The examples there are notoriously bad.

Comment: P.S. you can remove the code specific for ie6 and ie5

Answer (score 0):

Xmlhttprequest is deprecated by google chrome. It also has bad user-experience with other browsers. Next, it doesn't work in most cases for external xml files.
Therefore I recommend not to use it. In stead use $.ajax. Also it might be nicer to use document.getElementById instead of document.write. However this is up to you. Something like this should work:

```
$.ajax
    ({
      type: "GET",
      url: "file.xml",
      dataType: "xml",
      success: xmlParser // call function
    });

function xmlParser(xml) 
{
  HTML = "<table><tr><th>Artist</th><th>Title</th></tr>";
  var x=$(xml).find("CD");
  for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
  { 
    HTML += "<tr><td>";
    HTML += i+1;
    HTML += "</td><td>";
    HTML += $(x[i]).find("artist").text()
    HTML += "</td><td>";
    HTML += $(x[i]).find("title").text()
    HTML += "</td></tr>";
  }
  HTML += "</table>";
  document.getElementById("yourdiv").innerHTML = HTML;        
} // function xmlParser(xml)
```

Comment: This of course would presume one would  want to use jQuery, which is not mentioned by the OP at all.